# Oracle OTT error: "String index out of range -11"

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, occi

I am trying to convert a type into a c++ object using the following command:

```
OTT USERID=VCODER@localhost/153351 INTYPE=T_BODYIN.TPY OUTTYPE=T_BODYOUT.TPY CODE=CPP HFILE=T_BODY.H CPPFILE=T_BODY.CPP MAPFILE=T_BODY.CPPSET
```

This is the content of T_BODYIN.TPY:

```
case=lower
type t_body
```

And this is the content of the SQL TYPE:

```
CREATE TYPE t_body AS OBJECT (
  ID_SOLAR_SYSTEM   NUMBER,
  ID_BODY   NUMBER,
  NOME_CORPO    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ORBITING  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  PERIOD_OF_REVOLUTION  NUMBER,
  ORBITAL_SPEED NUMBER,
  INCLINATION_OF_AXIS_TO_ORBIT  NUMBER,
  EQUATORIAL_DIAMETER   NUMBER,
  MASS  NUMBER,
  DENSITY   NUMBER,
  ESCAPE_VELOCITY   NUMBER,
  SEMIMAJOR_AXIS    NUMBER,
  ORBIT_EXCENTRICITY    NUMBER,
  ORBIT_INCLINATION NUMBER,
  PERIHELION    NUMBER,
  APHELION  NUMBER,
  PX    NUMBER,
  PY    NUMBER,
  PZ    NUMBER,
  VX    NUMBER,
  VY    NUMBER,
  VZ    NUMBER
);
```

I get the message "String index out of range -11" from ott, any idea why?

P.S: First time using ott...

Comment: What does this have to do with the C++ language?  I don't see any C++ language in your question.

Comment: Maybe you have too many parameters to the `OTT` command line.  Does it have a method that you can put commands into a file and pass the file to `OTT`?